# How to display postgresql search results using PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

**The Problem**

Hello, I am creating a search function that will allow users to search for a specific E-Number and see whether it is derived from animals or not, basically seeing if it's vegan. I have successflly connected to the database using PHP on my website.

**The Code**

At the top of the page:

```
<?php       
// Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=***** port=*****
dbname=**** user=**** password=*****")
or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];

// Performing SQL query
$query = 'SELECT vegan FROM enumbers WHERE code = searchq';
}


?>
```

The search bar:

```
<div id="tablebox">
        <!-- Search bar -->
        <p>Is It Vegan?</p>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="searchEnumbers.php">
            <input name="search" type="text" size="30" maxlength="5" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
</div>
```

How will I now display the 'vegan' result that has been searched? I am unsure how to print the results.

**Update**

The column names in the enumbers table are: 'code', 'name', 'type', and 'vegan'.

```
<?php       
    // Connecting, selecting database
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=db.dcs.aber.ac.uk port=5432
    dbname=cs399030_16_17 user=sec17 password=Liverpool2112")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    //collect
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];

        // Performing SQL query
        $pg_query = 'SELECT vegan FROM enumbers WHERE code = '.$searchq;
        $result = pg_query($query);

        foreach($result as $r){ //If you have multiple records or $result
          echo "<p> Your ".$r->params." or ".$r['params']." here </p>"; //for instance
       }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer, as you have simple quote, the variable $searchq is not changed, and is read as a string. You should use double quotes like `"SELECT vegan FROM enumbers WHERE code = $searchq";` or concat it with dot (like in my answer).

Comment: Sorry, I didnt read it properly, It is still not showing any results.

Comment: You could try with: var_dump(pg_fetch_all($result)); to see if you have any result. If no, try to execute the query direct to the database, to search if any row match the condition. I assumed that you work in the file: 'searchEnumbers.php', right?

Comment: var_dump(pg_fetch_all($result)); does the exact same, once I press search, the page just seems to refresh. Yes, I am working in searchEnumbers.php

Comment: You should change the select for one that always shows results (like: 'SELECT * FROM enumbers'). If you couldn't see any result, the problem is in the DDBB connection. If you see the results, then is in the query.

Comment: The connection to the db is fine, I tested it earlier.  'SELECT * FROM enumbers', didnt work, I think it has something to do with no code on the page that prints the results. Here is the live page atm: http://users.aber.ac.uk/sec17/veganomnia/searchEnumbers.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142098/discussion-between-jp-aulet-and-rushfan2112).

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like:

```
<?php       
// Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=**** port=****
dbname=**** user=**** password=****")
or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

//collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];

   // Performing SQL query
   $query = 'SELECT vegan FROM enumbers WHERE code = '.$searchq; 

   // make the query with: pg_query
   // $result = pg_query($query);

   foreach($result as $r){ //If you have multiple records or $result
      echo "<p> Your ".$r->params." or ".$r['params']." here </p>"; //for instance
   }

   //you could use: var_dump(pg_fetch_all($result));
}

?>

<!-- If you want to show always the form. If not, put inside the else -->
<div id="tablebox">
        <!-- Search bar -->
        <p>Is It Vegan?</p>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="searchEnumbers.php">
            <input name="search" type="text" size="30" maxlength="5" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
</div>
```

Note this is `not the best` way to do it (you could use AJAX, and differents pages in order to now refresh the page), or others ways. But this could work as the way you want.

Check official documentation from PHP: http://php.net/manual/kr/function.pg-connect.php

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you JP. Aulet

Comment: This is not displaying any result, once I enter a enumber into the form and press search, nothing happens.

Comment: It misses a $ in the  $query = 'SELECT vegan FROM enumbers WHERE code = searchq'; . It should be:  $query = 'SELECT vegan FROM enumbers WHERE code = '.$searchq;

Comment: It is still doing the same thing

Comment: Does it need php by the form so it can print it there?

Comment: Update your code (paste it below the text: 'update'), and we could check what is happening. 

Post the information inside the database in enumbers table (the column names)